How to Save request.files in the Same Location send_file Pulls From in Python Flask
I have two endpoints made with python flask, the first allows a user to upload a file to the server and add the name to a database. The second fetches a name from the database and attempts to return the file with that name.
Both endpoints are using functions provided by flask, yet they attempt to pull from different directories.
Here's a simplified version of my first endpoint:
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']

    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    path = os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)

    file.save(path)

    saved_file: SavedFile = SavedFile(
        filename=filename
    )
    db.session.add(saved_file)
    db.session.commit()
    return "Uploading File"

Here's my second endpoint:
@app.route('/get/<string:name>', methods=['GET'])
def get(name: str):
    saved_file: SavedFile = SavedFile.query.filter_by(filename=name).first()

    path = os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], saved_file.filename)
    
    return send_file(path, as_attachment=True)

Notice specifically that in both endpoints, the path variable is defined in the exact same way. It joins the UPLOAD_FOLDER from the current_app with the filename.
Yet, when I first upload the file with the request: file.save(path) saves the file at the following location:

project-folder

UPLOAD_FOLDER <-- here
web_app_folder

app.py





When I late try to pull from the exact same path using the send_file(path) function, it tries to pull from this location:

project-folder

web_app_folder

UPLOAD_FOLDER <-- here
app.py





Notice the upload folder is now INSIDE the web app folder.
What causes these functions to pull from / save to separate locations even though they are told to pull / save to the exact same path? And importantly, how can I get send_file to pull from the same path as file.save?

define the fixed paths outside of the endpoints.

What do you mean? The UPLOAD_FOLDER is set to 'upload_folder' in the app config, that's the only place where I am defining a path.

Adding os.path.abspath to the send_file request fixes the issue for me by making the send_file request pull from the first folder location described in my question.

project-folder

UPLOAD_FOLDER <-- here
web_app_folder

app.py





The second endpoint becomes:
@app.route('/get/<string:name>', methods=['GET'])
def get(name: str):
    saved_file: SavedFile = SavedFile.query.filter_by(filename=name).first()

    path = os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], saved_file.filename)
    
    return send_file(os.path.abspath(path), as_attachment=True)

